# Hyperledger Fabric add new peer nodes with nodejs SDK

Tags: node.js, hyperledger-fabric

Does anyone know if it's possible to dynamically adding new peer nodes to the fabric network with SDK? I'm searching through documentation, and didn't seem to find the answers. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1):

Yes it is possible to dynamically add a node to the Fabric network.

Prior to adding the peer to the network you would need to stand up the peer i.e.

1. Generate Crypto config for peer
2. Obtain the crypto config for other peers, orderer and ca
3. Obtain the Channel.tx file
4. Start the docker containers required for the network

Once the above is done then you can use the Node.js APIs to join the peer to the network i.e. Create Channel, Join Channel, Install Chaincode, Instantiate Chaincode.